# append div to body on click jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

for adding a little **popup to a login** i´m using jquery to append a div and its content to the page **after the user clicks** on the button. I don´t know why, but everytime i click the button, the div appears normally but disappears again immediately. Please help.

The Problem is all about the `Forgot Password` button.

Here is the code:

```js
let form = $('form');

let passwordRequest = $('<button>');
passwordRequest.text('Forgot password?');
passwordRequest.attr('id', 'passwordRequest');
passwordRequest.appendTo(form);

function requestForgottenPassword() {
  let popup = $('<div />').appendTo(form);
  popup.attr('id', 'passwordPopup');
};

$(passwordRequest).on('click', function() {
  requestForgottenPassword();
});
```

```css
#passwordPopup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#logIn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 40px rgb(201, 201, 201);
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 200ms;
}

input[type=submit] {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(114, 114, 114);
  transition: 100ms;
}

#passwordRequest {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(62, 184, 255);
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 100ms;
  padding: 5px;
}

#passwordPopup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="logIn">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form>
    <h2>Username</h2>
    <input id="username" type="text">
    <h2>Password</h2>
    <input id="userPassword" type="password">
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://codepen.io/colintessarzick/pen/GRoMEWm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>` is by default `type="submit"` (even without the `type`) -
The issue you're experiencing is the form actually being submitted.

Use `type="button"`, or with your jQuery script:

```js
const passwordRequest = $("<button>", {
  text: "Forgot password?",
  id: "passwordRequest",
  type: "button",
  appendTo: form
});
```

Example:

```js
let form = $('form');

const passwordRequest = $("<button>", {
  text: "Forgot password?",
  id: "passwordRequest",
  type: "button",
  appendTo: form
});

function requestForgottenPassword() {
  let popup = $('<div />').appendTo(form);
  popup.attr('id', 'passwordPopup');
};

$(passwordRequest).on('click', function() {
  requestForgottenPassword();
});
```

```css
#passwordPopup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#logIn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 40px rgb(201, 201, 201);
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 200ms;
}

input[type=submit] {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(114, 114, 114);
  transition: 100ms;
}

#passwordRequest {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(62, 184, 255);
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 100ms;
  padding: 5px;
}

#passwordPopup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="logIn">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form>
    <h2>Username</h2>
    <input id="username" type="text">
    <h2>Password</h2>
    <input id="userPassword" type="password">
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but to understand ist right: if i don´t set the button to type=button, the form is submitted no matter what?

Comment: @cote exactly. `<button>` will always submit the wrapper `<form>`. Therefore it's always good to use `type="button"` (even when not using forms, just to get the habit). I know it's silly to write `<button type="button"` but that's just how it is.

Comment: @cote Imagine the early days of the internet - A form. The only logical-thinking to have a `<button>` would be to submit that form. Than later `type="submit"` was just for the sake of backward-compatibility and to allow the introduction of `type="button"` as an override. That's at least how I imagine things were done at the time ;)